# onbeforeunload - after user accepts confirmation box, javascript doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in onbeforeunload  function.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   if(ThereIsUnsavedWork)
   {
      return "Please save your work so it doesn't get lost.";
   }

   DoMoreStuff(); 
}
```

After the confirmation window, the DoMoreStuff() function isn't getting executed. Is there a way to make sure that javascript code executes after user accepts the confirmation window?

Comment: Nope, you can't delay the unload just because you'd like to do more stuff, that would be a christmas gift to spammers, as they could just delay the closing of a website indefinetely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `onbeforeunload` together with `onunload` as below.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   if(ThereIsUnsavedWork)
   {
      return "Please save your work so it doesn't get lost.";
   }
}

window.onunload = function () {
    DoMoreStuff();
}
```

Comment: Even when you press Cancel and leave is false, the page navigates away or closes.

Comment: Sure, what do you want if user click `cancel` and if user clicked `Ok`? I edited my answer.

Comment: It's an improvement. Now after you press 'cancel' it shows another confirmation box that asks if you want to close the browser. So user sees two confirmation boxes in a row.

Comment: Sorry, check my modified answer if you like to use `onunload` together with `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for a solution several hours, this is perfectly how it is supposed to work, thanks a lot!